# Suddenly the lower half of my LG Display started to flicker

Tags: windows-10, display, lg-monitor, distortion

as i was using my pc today my `LG Electronics 24MB56HQ-B` decided to go crazy. The lower half of the monitor starts to flicker every two seconds for about 3 seconds. Additionally the whole display is off (if you look at the notepad titlebar in the picture).

So far i tried to turn the display off and on again, i tried a factory reset. I tried switching from HDMI to VGA, changing from Intel HD Graphics to NVIDIA.

[Picture of Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pJuS.jpg)

[Video of flicker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccJHDUm-gcc)

Comment: Its a bad screen. Not much can be done, other than replace it.

Comment: By chance, did you put anything magnetic close to the monitor?

Comment: @Máté Juhász not as far as i know.

Comment: before you take the monitor for repair, test it with a different PC and also test with a different cable

Comment: the display panel seems to be ok...otherwise it would remain in such a state permanently,and thats good news because the panel is the most expensive part of monitor. If your monitor has a USB port, try playing a movie , but do try a different cable and different PC/Laptop

Comment: @Elmo I tried VGA and HDMI on two different computers and everywhere its the same. It looks like i got to buy a new one :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware issue.  Probably the internal power supply or driver board/section.  If not under warranty  best bet is to R/R the monitor

Comment: Damn, that's unfortunate. In this case i have to get a new one.